# Bargraph relative to a fixed point Matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a set of points relative to 1; I can do this on Excel but I'm struggling to do this in Python. The hardest part for me is to keep it into log scale for the Y-axis. If I have values

0.15 0.7 1.3 0.5 1.7,

How can I use matplotlib to achieve the same effect as shown below (done by Excel)? The best I've come up with so far is to subtract 1 from each value to actually center it around 0, but this ends up messing up the scaling.

**This is what I want:**

[image: This is the Excel version that I want to replicate in Python]

This is a **failed** attempt I get from Python:
[image]

Another **failed** attempt at Python gives me this; even though the Y-axis is in the log-range, notice that everything starts from the bottom, when I really want the values to be going up/down with respect to the centre, or 1, on the Y-axis[image]

Comment: Can you show an expected outcome? You want a log scale with consistent scaling for matplotlib, right?

Comment: Yep, check my edited post! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
# our imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# define the sample size and draw a random sample
N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)
sample = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(N))

# initialize our bar width and the subplot
width = 0.35
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot our indexes, sample using a blue color
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, sample, width, color='blue')

# Set our axes labels, title, tick marks, and then our x ticks.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores Example')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(('E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5'))

# Create a horizontal line at the origin
ax.axhline(y=0, color='black')

# Show our plot, do whatever
plt.show()
```

[image: MPL Example]

More examples and references can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html).

You can also use hex codes and set no outline for the bar graphs, and give some spacing for the actual plot, along with adding log axes:

Here is the final code to give a representation similar to your own:

```
# our imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# define the sample size and draw a random sample
N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)
sample = 10 ** np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=2, size=(N))

# initialize our bar width and the subplot
width = 0.35
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot our indexes, sample using a hex color and a 0 linewidth to get rid
# of the plot edges
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, sample, width, color='#50A6C2', linewidth=0)

# Set our axes labels, title, tick marks, and then our x ticks.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores Example')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(('E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5'))

# Create a horizontal line at the origin
ax.axhline(y=1, color='black')
# Set our limits
ax.set_xlim(-1, 5)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(0.01, 100)

# Show our plot, do whatever
plt.show()
```

[image: MPL With Log]

Comment: This is precisely not what I'm looking for :( the Y-axis isn't to log scale. So if we look at the Excel graph, notice that, even if the values are not transformed, the Y-axis itself is in a log range going from 0, 1, 10. I've effectively done what you've got already, but in that case the y-axis scale is linear rather than log.

Comment: Edited with a log axis.
Sorry, your example does not seem to have a log axis so I made a bad assumption.

Comment: Not a problem. It's getting there but I guess now it's a matter of, if there are bars over the black line (e.g. E1, E2, E3, E5) then how do we only show the top bits of the bar that's above the black line at 10^0? if we can get that, then SORTED!

Comment: That's easy, just set the scale and remove the axhline. You choose the scale. I only included that as an example of what you **could** do.